# Find out what merge base would have been

Tags: tfs, merge

How can you find out what the base (in a 3-way merge) between two changesets was?  I am trying to troubleshoot why a merge in the past did not automatically resolve as I expected.

I think I'm looking for a way to find out the same information as git's `merge-base` command.  If there's no command/way to do this, I'm happy to understand how the "base selection" works and manually work it through.

Answer (score 1):

[The `tf merges` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/656cs2x5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is probably as close as you're going to get. This will give you the history of the merges performed in TFS. If you explicitly state the source and target branch and ramp up the verbosity it might give you a clue as to what happened. Sorry for being vague but I don't have an example of a 3 way merge to test against.

`tf merges $/MySourceBranch $/MyTargetBranch /format:Detailed /showall`